# java.lang.Exception: WEB0113

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, netbeans-7

How to clear history of glass fish server 3.1.1 as i am getting this exception :

```
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.Exception: WEB0113: Virtual server [server] already has a web module [EnterpriseApplication2-war] loaded at [/EnterpriseApplication2-war]; therefore web module [EnterpriseApplication2#EnterpriseApplication2-war.war] cannot be loaded at this context path on this virtual server. 
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

My project is Java EE enterprise application (4 tier architecture) including MY SQL,EJB,JAXWS and JSF.

Comment: Looks like the server already has a web module or a war file deployed called EnterpriseApplication2.war in the deploy directory as per the application and on top of that you are packaging an war with the same name inside an ear, you have to delete the one outside ... I would thnk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception java.lang.Exception: WEB0113 relates the cache of the glassfish server. To solve this problem you have to :

1. Recreate the folder pathToServer/domain/YourDomain/generated

   mv generated generated-old

   mkdir generated
2. Recreate the folder pathToServer/domain/YourDomain/osgi-cache

   mv osgi-cache osgi-cache-old

   mkdir osgi-cache

   mkdir osgi-cache/felix
3. Restart the server

   asadmin restart-domain YourDomain

Answer (score 0):

If your app looks like it is not deployed anymore (not listed in admin gui), but you are still getting this error, you can try looking in /domains/domain1/applications and deleting the folder for your app there.

Comment: If you found my answer to be less than helpful, please elaborate why.